# VCS file colors not showing in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am using Android Studio 3.1.4.
I have configured git in Android studio but I am facing one problem. When I edit or create any file, it gets color-coded in Android Studio. But all the ignored files don't get the colors.

[image]

As shown in the above image, I have added `google-services.json` in `.gitignore`, but it still has black color. 
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What color do you expect it to have?

Comment: According to "https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-status-highlights.html", it should have "Olive" color.

Comment: Is the VCS root of the modules registered? (check settings -> Version Control and verify the directory of your module is linked to the repo URL you expect it to point to)